# Is it realistic for a single server to handle 2000 HTTP requests per second?

Tags: java, json, http, servlets

I am building a Java-based web service (using JSON as a data encoding) that will need to handle up-to 2,000 HTTP requests per second.  The processing required for each request is almost negligible (a HashMap.put() method call), parsing the JSON would probably be the dominant overhead.

I am wondering whether a single High-Memory Quadruple Extra Large EC2 instance (68GB RAM, 8 cores, 64-bit) would be capable of handing as much as 2,000 HTTP requests per second?

I realize that an exact answer will be difficult, I'm just wondering whether this is within the bounds of possibility, or whether I'm smoking crack.

I'm currently using the [SimpleWeb](http://www.simpleframework.org/) web framework, although I've noticed that it doesn't seem to be maintained currently.  Can people recommend alternative embeddable HTTP servers that would be well suited to this kind of high-volume usage?

Comment: Why would you want to limit it to a single server, which has obvious problems in terms of outages etc as well as handling that many requests per second. If you work out how to scale out, it'll kill two birds with one stone.

Comment: This question is unanswerable in its current form. But for reference, here is a SO topic with a user who got his single server processing 15k per sec - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193012/how-to-handle-2000-requests-sec-on-tomcat.

Comment: 2000 req/s could be possible, but there are lot of opened questions, like bandwidth, IO, Best way is to make make a performance test and see the numbers for your specific test, your question is to general to answer.

Comment: For the given hardware 2k requests per second should not be a big deal. The only concern would be the network speed and the message size. If they are not a bottleneck, you could achive this with pretty much any http server. Infact jetty or netty can support higher load, high number of connections etc. I have worked with a netty server with a lesser hardware configuration than yours and supported many thousands msgs/sec. I had hundreds of clients connected and it was not ec2.

Answer (score 2):

2000 requests per second (or 2 krps) should be well within the realm of possibility for a Java servlet, provided that you don't introduce huge bottlenecks and that the framework you are using doesn't suck too much. Given that apparently you are not accessing any backends, the task should be CPU-bound and scale very well.

The [JSON serialization](http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r9&hw=peak&test=json) test of the Web Framework Benchmarks shows a lot of Java frameworks that give very good results; even with [20 database queries](http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r9&hw=peak&test=query) results are still very well over 2 krps. On Amazon they are using [m1.large](http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=environment&hw=peak&test=json) instances which are smaller than the ones you plan to use (c3.4xlarge, I gather).

You might try [Undertow](http://undertow.io/) which provides a convenient servlet API and is [well maintained](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow). [Netty](http://netty.io/) is another possibility, although it has its own API.

Note: I realize that the question is a bit old, but the problem should still be valid.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible, in accordance to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444267/how-to-write-a-high-performance-netty-client), [Netty](http://netty.io/) can handle way over 100 000 interactions per second. Some JSON parser can convert request string into JSON object or maybe you can even use a binaray variant of it, [BSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117167/creating-bson-object-from-json-string), as describe here (if the messages are long or very complex). From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332741/what-is-the-theoretical-maximum-number-of-open-tcp-connections-that-a-modern-lin) looks like the number of connections that a server with recent operating system can handle is over 300 000 so much more than would be needed for your task.

Of course, this also depends on which actions do you need to take to handle the request that may be a limiting factor.