# How to write a high performance Netty Client

Tags: tcp, protocol-buffers, netty

I want an extremely efficient TCP client to send google protocol buffer messages.  I have been using the Netty library to develop a server/client.

In tests the server seems to be able to handle up to 500k transactions per second, without to many problems, but the client tends to peak around 180k transactions per second.

I have based my client on the examples provided in the Netty documentation, but the difference is I just want to send the message and forget, I don't want a response (which most of the examples get).  Is there anyway to optimize my client, so that I can achieve a higher TPS ?

Should my client maintain multiple channels, or should I be able to achieve a higher throughput than this with a single channel?

Comment: the timing does indeed *sound* like the client is waiting for a response... just a thought - since it sounds like a fairly simple service, have you tried just using a raw socket?

Comment: if any one resolved issue for this kind of client , can you please share the client code for example with which netty version use? currently i am stuck with version changes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1) If the client is only interested in sending, not in receiving, you can always disable reading from channel like below

```
channel.setReadable(false);
```

2) You can increase the throughput very easily by having multiple client channels per client, and also it can scale too.

3) and you can do following tweaks to improve the performance in general (for read/ write)

- Its better to have a SEDA like pipline by adding a EXecutionHandler with OrderdMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor, (with min, max channel memory with optimal value)

  ```
  bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
      @Override
      public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
          return Channels.pipeline(
                  executionHandler1,//sharable
                  new MessageDecoderHandler(),
                  new MessageEncoderHandler(),
                  executionHandler2,//sharable
                  new BusinessLogicHandler1(),
                  new BusinessLogicHandler2());
      }
  });
  ```
- Setting the writeBufferHighWaterMark of the channel to optimal value (Make sure that setting a big value will not create congestion)

  `bootstrap.setOption("writeBufferHighWaterMark", 10 * 64 * 1024);`
- Setting the SO_READ, SO_WRITE buffer size

  `bootstrap.setOption("sendBufferSize", 1048576);
   bootstrap.setOption("receiveBufferSize", 1048576);`
- Enabling the TCP No delay

  `bootstrap.setOption("tcpNoDelay", true);`

Comment: Thanks, One question on point 2).  What is the best way to do this, should I create multiple channels, and put the handlers for them in some sort of worker queue, to process requests ?

Comment: @Dave take a look at this answer to see how client can use multiple connections http://stackoverflow.com/a/7905761/596720

Comment: I have found that `setReadable(false)` is probably not a good idea unless you have a way to know that the remote end disconnected without trying to read the channel. `read()` returns `-1` when the remote end hangs up.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if "tcpNoDelay" helps to improve the throughput. Delay is there to improve the performance. None the less, I tried it and saw that the throughput actually fell more than 90%.