# Optimal setting for socket send buffer for sending image files on Netty

Tags: sockets, tcp, netty

I'm looking into implementing a HTTP image server in Netty and I was wondering what the optimal Send Buffer Size should be:

```
ie. bootstrap.setOption("sendBufferSize", 1048576);
```

I've read [How to write a high performance Netty Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444267/how-to-write-a-high-performance-netty-client) but I was wondering what are the consequences of setting this value too small or too large.

The images I serve are mostly around 100K to 5MB (avg 1MB). I'm thinking a large (1MB) value would cause the OS memory to be filled with TCP buffered data but is there a performance penalty of setting it to a small value (ie. 8192KB)?

Comment: The basic answer is 'the larger the better', but note that the receiver's socket receive buffer must be at least as large to derive any benefit at all, and note the caveat in @TrustinLee's answer.

Comment: @EJP is this due the nature or specification of TCP/IP? Are the buffer sizes are coordinated at start of connection and that the sender will mirror the lower of its buffer size settings or the receiver's buffer size?

Comment: These buffers are used to implement TCP windowing. The receiver advertises the current amount of room in its receive buffer with each ACK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-hisock/index.html#N100D7) useful.

You might also need to adjust the size of the peer's receive buffer size.  In this case, please make sure you set it to the server socket.  Otherwise, you'll be capped at 64KiB.

Comment: Thanks Trustin! The article gives me a framework to calculate the buffer settings. Looks like the "optimal" setting is not dependent on my payload - and is affected by how much RAM you have as well as traffic expectations.

I'm assuming by peer you mean the client (ie. browser?) In my case I don't have control over that so its pointless to set it higher than 64K?

Comment: I guess you can simply assume the default values of the browsers your users are using and begin testing with that value.

Comment: @trustin , that article link is not working anymore. Do you have any alternative link?

Comment: Here is the closest snapshot from archive.org of the link referenced by @trustin: https://web.archive.org/web/20130417073743/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-hisock/index.html