# Tomcat doing 15K req/second on a single server using Jersey Jax-RS

Tags: java, tomcat, scalability, membase

I tried testing things on a VPS, and came close to 10K requests per second, and that was a `simple 'hello world' servlet`, let alone making a call to membase.

My VPS was a 2 x Intel Xeon X5570, quad-core “Nehalem” architecture.

Note:  I'm not a java expert, nor a tomcat expert, this was on default settings.

Does anyone else deal with such high traffic that could shed some light?

I used apache bench, and I ran it maybe 4-5 times, doing about 100K requests to the server.

original: [how to handle 2000+ requests/sec on tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193012/how-to-handle-2000-requests-sec-on-tomcat/7194290#7194290)

Comment: hoping @Brian Roach can chime in :)

Comment: Are you sure you weren't *client* bound? We had the hardest time getting accurate numbers from any of the "testing tools" for the simple fact that we'd max out the client before tomcat. We ended up writing our own simple test classes that spawned enough threads to keep the query rate high enough to get accurate numbers. Also, what @BalusC says below.

Comment: @Brian good point, I was running it on the same machine also.  But what gets me it was as simple as you can get 'hello world', I imagine yours has way more logic like authentication etc, then writing to a db. amazing though, blows ruby out of the water!

Comment: [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) is an invaluable webserver stress test tool. Its UI is pretty spartan and not exactly tasteful and user friendly, but it does its job very well.

Comment: We keep persistent connections to membase via a connection pool and our median query time is < 1ms; there's not a lot of overhead there. The most overhead is probably in the JSON serialization, but that's pretty speedy as well. We're also not running in a virtualized environment.

Comment: @BalusC - I thought so as well but found even running on several machines JMeter simply couldn't max out our tomcat server. With that being said, it could have been user error, but it was trivial to write a quick and dirty multi-threaded app to beat up our tomcat servers.

Comment: I find that java is not getting its fair share of respect, it sure has a mature toolset and community behind it, interesting!

Comment: @Brian why don't you open source that? or paste it in a gist :)

Comment: with that amount of traffic, it probably speeds things up by reducing what tomcat logs to its log files also.

Comment: @codecompleting - yeah, in production we don't really care about anything except errors so we adjust the logging accordingly.

Comment: @BrianRoach dual quad core w/32gb ram at softlayer are like $1200/mo. yikes.

Comment: @BrianRoach is there a formula between # of cors, and maxthread settings for tomcat? are you using NIO also?

Comment: @BrianRoach what kind of data size are you saying in each call? small like 10-20K?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Turn on NIO (Non-Blocking IO). This is not by default turned on. Without NIO, every HTTP connection is handled by a single thread and the limit is dependent on the amount of threads available. With NIO, multiple HTTP connections can be handled by a single thread and the limit is dependent on amount of heap memory available. With about 2GB you can go up to 20K connections.

Turning on NIO is a matter of changing the `protocol` attribute of the [`<Connector>`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) element in Tomcat's `/conf/server.xml` to `"org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"`.

```xml
<Connector
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    port="80"
    redirectPort="8443"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    compression="on" />
```

Comment: I was ready jetty might be better when you have many short lived requests, true?

Comment: I have never used Jetty closely. From what I've read on Java related forums and question&answer sites throughout the past 8 years, nothing has motivated me enough to ever take Jetty serious. I don't stop you from trying and benchmarking it yourself though.

Comment: wondering if there are recommendations on how many threads per core one should set in tomcat?  I'm guessing you can tell it that in the config? i.e. max threads  Or does it just work out of the box knowing you have multi cores etc.

Comment: Click the blueish `<Connector>` part in my answer. It guides you to the documentation with a valuable overview of all possible settings. Last but not least: measuring is knowing. A lot depends on underlying hardware and software(!).

Comment: strange, switching over to Nio actually slowed things down (on both single and multi core vm's), I even tried various combinations of apache bench requests and concurrent connections (-n and -c switches).  Also, per request times where about .2 ms more.  I was gettign maybe 20% higher rps rates with http 1.1 or Http11Protocol (both are the same).  Strange no?

Comment: Maybe it's the VPS platform. Hard to tell.

Comment: I doubt its ec2, it has to be a config issue, or NIO is just slower lol.

Comment: If the answer doesn't help, and even makes things worse, why is it marked as answered?

Comment: I'm sorry for off-topic question, but does switching to specified connector in Tomcat enable `Asynchronous I/O` feature which is used by `node.js` community as undisputable preference? :)