# Configuring Server for handling 10000 request

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, tomcat6, glassfish-3

I am developing an example web-service using RESTFull Api. I want to know how we can manage more then 10000 or more request at a time using tomcat server. Do we control it by only database side parameter configuration (Max_User or Max_Active_Connection), or there is something more in Application server side as well. Say any field in web.xml or any limitation to the number of concurrent connection.

Is that the RAM size and the database side parameters control this or any other way?

In one line, How and what factor of a server(s)(For Java) handle and limit the concurrent connection?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There is no limit: neither in java nor in tomcat. If required then you can add your own throttling logic.

Comment: see maxConnections at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html  - you definately want some db pooling

Answer (score 1):

Your target of 10000 or more simultaneous requests is going to end up a function of your whole stack more than just a function of Tomcat.  If you write a Servlet to do nothing more than always return 200, does that get you 10000 simultaneous requests?  Have you tested it?  Maybe this guy has an answer for you:  [how to handle 2000+ requests/sec on tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193012/how-to-handle-2000-requests-sec-on-tomcat)

Comment: That web service method will do database query, say all crud operation.